# Autocorrelation Functions <---> Pair Correlation Functions

Tags: statistical-mechanics, correlation-functions, covariance

Are there any ways to convert an [autocorrelation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) to a [pair correlation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_distribution_function), and vice versa?

Comment: This seems to be a misunderstanding. Autocorrelation function is derived from the correlation between $y(t)$ and $y(y+\Delta t)$ and this autocorrelation is a function of the lag $\Delta t$. It *is* a pair correlation function between two things, namely the value of a function and the value of a function which is obtained from the first one by a shift in $t$. If you ask about "pair correlations", what are the two things in the pair? Obviously, if something in the pair is something completely different than the original function or its shifts, the pair correlation will have nothing to do with..

Comment: ...with the autocorrelation of the function we started with.

Comment: If your pairs are those in the "radial correlation function", there won't be any relationship, either. The autocorrelation is about the delaying in time while the radial correlation function is about shifting the objects in the radial direction. Those are different variables in which objects may be moved so the correlation functions won't be related, either.

Comment: @Luboš Motl, There is a typo in your comment. You meant "...the correlation between $y(t)$ and $y(t+\Delta t)$..."

Comment: @TopekaCanvas, What is the variable whose auto-correlation you have in mind? The radial distribution function can be related to the spatial auto-correlation function of the density. Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: @Vijay, that was my reading of the question.

Comment: Hi Vijay, yes, that's right. Spatial autocorrelation function to g(r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the density auto-correlation function as
$$S_{\rho\rho} = \langle \delta \rho(\mathbf{x}_1) \delta \rho(\mathbf{x}_2)\rangle$$
where $\delta \rho(\mathbf{x}) = \rho(\mathbf{x}) - \langle \rho(\mathbf{x}) \rangle$ is deviation from the local mean value.

The Fourier transform of $S_{\rho\rho}$ is related to the structure-factor
$$S(\mathbf{q}) = \langle \rho \rangle^2 (2\pi)^d \delta(\mathbf{q}) + \frac{1}{V}\int d^d x_1 d^d x_2 e^{-i \mathbf{q} \cdot (\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2)} S_{\rho\rho}$$
where $\langle \rho \rangle$ is the average density of the whole system, i.e., $V \langle \rho \rangle = \int d^d \mathbf{x} \, \rho(\mathbf{x})$.

The structure factor $S(\mathbf{q})$ is related to the pair-correlation function $g(\mathbf{x})$ via
$$S(\mathbf{q}) = \langle \rho \rangle \Big[1 + \langle \rho \rangle \int d^d \mathbf{x} \, g(\mathbf{x}) e^{-i \mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{x}} \Big]$$

If the system is isotropic, then $g(\mathbf{x}) = g(|\mathbf{x}|)$ is called the radial-distribution function.

Most of these relations are already in the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_distribution_function) linked in the question.

Comment: Vijay, Qmechanic edited the question to add the Wikipedia links.

Comment: Thank you very much Vijay! How would you go about isolating either function? I've been trying ntegration by parts to isolate $S_{\rho\rho}$

Comment: What do you mean by isolating either function? Do you meant how $S_{\rho\rho}$ and $g$ are related in real-space?

Comment: If I had an expression for $g(r)$, I was wondering if there is a way to calculate $S_{pp}$ without resorting to doing it numerically?

Comment: You cannot back out $S_{\rho\rho}$ since, as I said, $g(r)$ is for an isotropic system.